# How many bitcoins were transferred from one wallet to another?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, blockchain, bitcoin

The problem is simple: I want to query how many BTC were transferred from Wallet A to Wallet B with as many hops as blocks in the blockchain.

Ex.

```
A transferred 1 BTC to C and 1 BTC to D.
C transferred 0.1 to B
D transferred 0.5 to E and 0.5 to F
E transferred 0.1 to B
```

Total 0.2 BTC transferred from A to B

I figure I could do this by using bigquery on the blockchain. The problem is that I do not know how to create a recursive query like that. My SQL skills tend to zero.

The cause is noble. I have few addresses that were used in what proved to be a ponzi scheme 1. I have other set of addresses that are being used in ANOTHER scheme, which I believe is another scam (2) laundering money from scheme 1.

I know who is the person behind scam 2.

If I prove that a great amount of BTCs from the first scam went to the wallets related to the second scam, it could be strong indication that they are the same.

Note that I've said a great amount of BTCs. I know that some of BTCs may wind up at the wallets of scheme 2 by chance, but for the majority to end up there is not at all a coincidence.

Disclosure: I am **NOT** obtaining any financial benefits from this, I only intend to reveal this scammer.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results as *text tables*.

Answer (score -1):

Since you did not post a data structure your mileage may vary. Here is a hypothetical (I know zero about bitcoin data structures) bitcoin chain structure. Use a recursive CTE to create an anchor and self call. I am using Source and target below, however, they could be exchanged with bitcoin semantics.

[Sql Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/49b91/1/0)

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(ChainID INT, SourceID INT, TargetID INT, Amount INT)
INSERT @T VALUES
(1,100,300,1),
(2,900,800,1),
(1,100,400,1),
(2,800,700,1),
(1,300,200,1),
(1,400,500,1),
(2,700,600,1),
(1,500,600,1),
(1,500,200,1),
(2,600,500,1),
(2,500,400,1)

 DECLARE @ChainID INT = 2

 --Get the first source of a chain !If natural order, if there is a more suitable order field then use it!
 DECLARE @StartID INT = (SELECT SourceID FROM (SELECT SourceID,RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ChainID) FROM @T WHERE ChainID = @ChainID ) AS X WHERE RN=1)

;WITH RecursiveWalk AS
(   
        --Anchor
    SELECT 
        SourceID, 
        TargetID = T.TargetID,
        LevelID = 1
    FROM 
        @T T
    WHERE 
        T.SourceID = @StartID AND ChainID = @ChainID

    UNION ALL

        --Recursive bit
    SELECT 
        T.SourceID, 
        TargetID = T.TargetID,
        LevelID = LevelID + 1 
    FROM 
        @T T 
        INNER JOIN RecursiveWalk RW ON T.SourceID = RW.TargetID
    WHERE
        ChainID=@ChainID
)

SELECT 
    SourceID,
    TargetID,
    LevelID
FROM 
    RecursiveWalk
```